# AttributeError: Can't get attribut *attribute name*

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, oop

I don't understand what the error is. Here is a small code related to **OOP** (By the type of database creation):

```
class Employ:
    def __init__(self, name=None, age=0, pay=0, job=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pay = pay
        self.job = job
    def __str__(self):
        return ('%s\n%s ==> %s'%(self.name, self.job, self.pay))
    def LastName(self):
        return self.name.split()[-1]
    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        self.pay *= (1.0+(percent/100))

class Manager(Employ):
    def __init__(self, name, age, pay):
        Employ.__init__(self, name, age, pay, job='manager')
    def giveRaise(self, percent, bonus=0.1):
        Employ.giveRaise(self, percent + bonus)
```

Next, I enclose the test code in the instruction and import the 'shelve' module `__name__ == '__main__':`

```
    ...Employ.giveRaise(self, percent + bonus)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bob = Employ('Bob Smith', 42, 40000, 'dev')
    sue = Employ('Sue Jones', 45, 50000, 'hdw')
    tom = Employ('Tom Hanks', 54)
    pavel = Employ('Pavel Savelev', 20, 100000, 'fsdev')
    john = Manager('John Silverhand', 127, 60000)

    db = shelve.open('filename')
    db['bob'] = bob
    db['sue'] = sue
    db['tom'] = tom
    db['pavel'] = pavel
    db['john'] = john
    print(db['bob'])
    for i in db:
        print(i,'==>', db[i].name, db[i].pay)
    db.close()
```

After that, when I create the file I need, I want to output some values from there by:

```
import shelve


db = shelve.open('filename')
for key in db:
    print(key, '=>\n ', db[key])
    print('=='*8)
db.close()
```

*(new file)*

Both in the `db[key]` instruction and in similar ones, I get the **AttributeError error: Can't get attribute Employee**

However, if I import the Employ and Manager classes into a new module and in this new module I write everything that was enclosed in the instruction `__name__ == '__main__':`, then I will be able to get attributes from the new file and there will be no AttributeError error

Why?

Comment: So what's actually in `db` then?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: If you're talking about the last bit of code where you read from the file and print each item, then you're getting the error because that code has no definitions for Employ and Manager.  For the `shelve` module to be able to recreate those types, it has to have definitions for them.  You need to define Employ and Manager before trying to read a file that contains shelved values of those types.

Comment: @CryptoFool I get an error at the end, where I try to read the file

Comment: @CryptoFool Aren't classes defined in instances?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "instances".  If you are expecting the definitions of those objects to be in the file itself, that's not how it works.  What's written to the file is just a reference to the class for each object in the file.  When the file is read, the definitions of those objects have to be available in the code.